# Pycharm throws this error : ImportError: No module named pymongo

Tags: pycharm, pymongo

If I run the same program from the terminal it works fine.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/anilthorat/PycharmProjects/mongodb/update.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anilthorat/PycharmProjects/mongodb/update.py", line 1, in 
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named pymongo

Answer (score 0):

You probably have at least two Python environments on your system, and your terminal and PyCharm are using different ones. Try:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip install pymongo
```

... to ensure you have PyMongo installed for that environment.